# Python 3.5 AttributeError: 'Player' object has no attribute 'posX'

Tags: python, inheritance, pygame, attributeerror, python-3.5

So I've found some answers to similar questions, but they don't seem to work for my case. Below is the class file I'm attempting to utilize:

```
class Characters(object):
def __init__(self,health,posX,posY,width,height,dead,moveSpeed,yMove,xMove):
    self.health = health
    self.posX = posX
    self.posY = posY
    self.width = width
    self.height = height
    self.dead = dead
    self.yMove = yMove
    self.xMove = xMove


class Player(Characters):
def __init__(self,images,gameOver):
    self.images = images
    self.gameOver = gameOver

def move(self):

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            self.gameOver = True

    keysPressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keysPressed[pygame.K_w]:
        self.yMove = -self.moveSpeed
        self.image = self.images[1]
    if keysPressed[pygame.K_s]:
        self.yMove = self.moveSpeed
        self.image = self.images[0]
    if keysPressed[pygame.K_a]:
        self.xMove = -self.moveSpeed
        self.image = self.images[2]
    if keysPressed[pygame.K_d]:
        self.xMove = self.moveSpeed
        self.image = pygame.transform.flip(self.images[2],True,False)

    self.posX += self.xMove
    self.posY += self.yMove

    return (self.image,self.posX,self.posY,self.gameOver)
```

And below this is the part of the main function I'm trying to use to call the module `Player.move()`:

```
gameOver = False
playerPos = [None,(surfaceDim[0]/2,surfaceDim[1]/2),gameOver]

while not playerPos[2]:

    player = Characters.Player(playerImgs,gameOver)
    playerPos = player.move()
```

When I do this, it tells me that `'Player' object has no attribute 'posX'`. From my understanding, Player should be inheriting attributes from Characters, but here it isn't. I have also tried using the `super()` method, but then it tells me I'm missing variables. Any suggestions?

Comment: You do need to use super. You should show how you tried and what error you got.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialise the Character class like so:

```
class Player(Characters):
def __init__(self,images,gameOver):
    Characters.__init__(self)
```